# puppet agent is not reflecting my changes

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have installed puppet enterprise 3.7.2 on centos 7.Both Puppet master and agent is working .I can able to view the node from puppet enterprise console and attached screen shot.

[image]

I created the manifest file /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests/node.pp with the following content on puppet server.

```
node 'puppet.client.net' {
  file { '/tmp/hello':
    content => "Hello, world\n",
  }
}
```

After I executed the following  command on master:

```
 #puppet agent apply  nodes.pp
```

And then Executed the following command on  client node :

```
#puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for puppet.client.net
Info: Applying configuration version '1424179235'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 2.12 seconds
```

Puppet node does not pick any changes from master.

Comment: can you run it with debug option and paste the output? `puppet agent -t --debug`

Answer (score 1):

The master will typically try and find manifests in `site.pp`, not `nodes.pp`, as that is the default setting for `manifest` in `puppet.conf`.

Try setting

```
manifest=/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/manifests
```

or better yet, use directory environments from the start.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried above your answer.still i am facing the same issue.

Comment: Debugging steps - 1. Put a `fail()` call into the `node` block, see if it takes effect. 2. If not, put it outside the `node` block, see if it takes effect. 3. Examine `puppet master --configprint all` on the master find out why your manifest is not considered. 4. Stop the master and run a debug instance using `puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose --debug` then request the catalog.